# Update recyclerview single row data when spinner item data is changed

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onitemselectedlistener

I have a `RecyclerView` as given in picture below.

[image]

I get the food item data from the server and bind them to `RecyclerView` as above.

Food items are assigned in `foodItemList` array list which has `foodItemTypeList` array. In `foodItemTypeList` array list, values of types and their corresponding prices are stored.

What I want is when the user selects a food type (for example medium), the corresponding unit price is updated.

Here is the `FoodItemAdapter` class:

```
public class FoodItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodItemAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
    private List<FoodItem> foodItemList;
    Context context;
    String token;

    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView food_name, food_unit_price;
        Spinner food_item_type;
        public ImageView food_item_image;
        public Button viewDetail;

        public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            food_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_name);
            food_item_type = (Spinner) itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_item_type);
            viewDetail = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewDetail);
            food_unit_price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_unit_price);
            food_item_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_item_image);
        }
    }

    public FoodItemAdapter(Context context, List<FoodItem> foodItemList,String token) {
        this.foodItemList = foodItemList;
        this.context = context;
        this.token = token;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.food_items_item, parent, false);
        return new CustomViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        FoodItem foodItem = foodItemList.get(position);
        holder.food_name.setText(foodItem.getFood_name());
        holder.viewDetail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        holder.food_unit_price.setText(foodItem.getFood_unit_price()+" AF");

        if(foodItem.getFood_item_image()!=null && !foodItem.getFood_item_image().isEmpty()){
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(foodItem.getFood_item_image())
                    // To fit image into imageView
                    .resize(50, 50)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(holder.food_item_image);
        } else {
            Log.d("Food Item Image:", "Food Item image is either empty or null");
        }

        List<FoodItemType> foodItemTypeList = new ArrayList<>();
        foodItemTypeList = foodItem.getFoodItemTypeList();
        ArrayAdapter userAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.spinner, foodItemTypeList);
        holder.food_item_type.setAdapter(userAdapter);
        holder.food_item_type.setOnItemSelectedListener(new
            AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int
                        position, long id) {

                    FoodItemType foodItemType = (FoodItemType) (holder.food_item_type).getSelectedItem();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked: " +
                            foodItemType.getFood_unit_price(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    FoodItem foodItemNew = new FoodItem(foodItemList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getFood_item_id(),foodItemList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getFood_category_id(),foodItemList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getFood_name(),foodItemList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getFood_item_image(),foodItemList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getFood_item_desc(), foodItemType.getFood_item_type_id(),foodItemType.getFood_item_type_name(),foodItemType.getFood_unit_price(), foodItemList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getFoodItemTypeList());
                    foodItemList.set(holder.getAdapterPosition(),foodItemNew);
                    notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // todo for nothing selected
                }
            });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return foodItemList.size();
    }

}
```

A part of my `FoodItemsFragment` class is as below:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_food_item);
foodItemAdapter = new FoodItemAdapter(getActivity(),foodItemList, token);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerView.setAdapter(foodItemAdapter);
foodItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

My problem is: When I scroll `RecyclerView`, the view is loaded multiple times (a kind of lagging) and when I change the foody type (for example: to medium), nothing happens.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this click toast show when you change the food?

Comment: `Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked: " + foodItemType.getFood_unit_price(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` is just for debugging purpose. When the `recyclerview` is loaded, the price value for type _small_ is showing multiple times.

Comment: I thought the problem is `onBindViewHolder`. it is calling multiple times during scroll and causes lagging. I don't know if it is the correct way to implement `setOnItemSelectedListener` in `onBindViewHolder` method

Comment: How about image Size?

Comment: Did you try to load same list without images?

Comment: @danishjo did you try my answer?

Comment: @ReazMurshed I added a comment to your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you have another field in your `FoodItem` class, which is `selectedFoodType`. This will hold the index of the type selected. By default, initialize the value with 0 and when an item is selected from the drop-down list, just update the corresponding `FoodItem`'s  `selectedFoodType` accordingly.

Another thing is, you do not have to create a new `FoodItem` each time you are changing the type of the `FoodItem`. You need to have the `selectedFoodType` only and then call the `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

So the code should look like the following. Inside your `onItemSelected` function, do the following.

```
int foodType = foodItemTypeList.get(position);
FoodItem foodItem = foodItemNew.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
foodItem.setSelectedFoodType = foodType;
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Please note that I have not tested this code. Please modify as per your need. Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried your answer. I noticed that creating new food was caused lagging. When I use `notifyDataSetChanged()` the spinner dropdown freezes. So, I changed to `notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition());` this time when I select a food item type (for example medium), it refreshes back to the small.

Comment: You need to set the selected item in the spinner as well then. Use the `selectedFoodType` for the spinner selected item in your `onBindViewHolder`.